# How to get output of unique words in a file using regex within linux commands?

Tags: regex, unix

How to get output of unique words in a file using regex within linux commands?

example.txt:

```
(my name is gaurav, how are you, I am doing great, Thanks you!!)
```

I am trying tr for this but getting comma word as different word.

```
cat example.txt | tr ' ' '\n' |sort | uniq
```

And I obtain:

```
I
Thanks
am
are
doing
gaurav,
great,
how
is
me
you!!)
you,
```

Comment: I am trying to translate all the whitespaces in a new line then taking unique words. Not sure how to use grep for this.

Comment: Please edit your samples of input and expected output in code tags  in your question to make it clear. Thank you

Comment: You can try: `cat example.txt | tr -d '[:punct:]' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u`.

Comment: @nikolaos, `tr -d '[:punct:]'` will do interesting things with apostrophes and hyphens, when they go between two letters...

Comment: Let suppose I have some extra spaces in between two words, but I am just using one space for tr in one new line then how can i get rid of that ?

Comment: @alexis, that's a good point, however the OP hasn't specified all the possible characters their text may have; the example has no apostrophes or hyphens and thus my comment can serve for them as a good starting point (i.e., a working solution for the example input); this is a reason why my "answer" is a comment and not a "real" answer (as providing one, needs more details in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sh
grep -oE '[[:alnum:]_]+' example.txt | sort | uniq
```

`grep -oE '[[:alnum:]_]+' example.txt` extracts words only, without punctuation, from the file.